# can you create a JSON string that jQuery.each(arg, function(i,val){} can parse?

Tags: c#, jquery, json

I have a C# class that I want to convert to a JSON string, send it to my web client and using jQuery, parse that into an array of JSON objects.  Is that possible?

here is some example code

```
    class mnuitm  
    {  
       public string prop1;  
       public string prop2;  
       public List<mnuitm> children;  
    }  

I am trying to build a string that looks like this:  
    {  
      "prop1":"value in prop1",  
      "prop2":"value in prop2",  
      "children":[  
          {  
          "prop1":"value in prop1",  
          "prop2":"value in prop2"  
          },  
          {  
          "prop1":"value in prop1",  
          "prop2":"value in prop2"  
          }  
        ]  
    }, ... (repeat n times, children may not be there or have any number of child items  

    }  //closing bracket
```

my client makes an ajax call which returns the above as a string
and I'm trying to parse it with jQuery, but it isn't working.

Is this possible.  If not, how should I do it

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `jQuery.getJSON()`

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Alternatively, you can just do `JSON.parse(str)` in the browsers that support it (I know Chrome/FF4 for sure). For better cross-browser support, use `jQuery.parseJSON()`.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: Used $.parseJSON(), but I had a couple of errors in my JSON string.  To locate those errors and resolve them, I used JSON Checker, download at http://www.raboof.com/projects/jsonchecker/

Answer (score 0):

actually if your web service/web page just returns the javascript chunk then the user can just retrieve that chunk and use it like an object without any conversion.

that's because json is native to javascript and [you can just call it like below](http://jsfiddle.net/upANw/):

```
 var obj = {  
      "prop1":"value in prop1",  
      "prop2":"value in prop2",  
      "children":[  
          {  
          "prop1":"value in prop1",  
          "prop2":"value in prop2"  
          },  
          {  
          "prop1":"value in prop1",  
          "prop2":"value in prop2"  
          }  
        ]  
    };
alert(obj.prop1);
alert(obj.children[0].prop1);
```

or are you trying to convert that into a different class/object type in javascript? 
then you can parse it and convert it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use [JavascriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)

Or [JSON.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx)